# How to show which image a GCE VM was created from?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I need to figure out which image was used to create a virtual machine in my organization's Google Cloud / Compute Engine project.

I don't see this information on the Virtual Machine overview page (within https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances) or via the SDK using `gcloud compute instances describe`.

This information wasn't readily apparent to me after a quick google search or scanning the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Information about which image was used upon the creation of a Google Compute Engine instance can be retrieved by running this [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/describe) from the Cloud Shell of your Console:

```
    `gcloud compute disks describe [Your-Instance-name]`
```

The image name will be listed next to `sourceImage` and the id next to `sourceImageId`. In case the GCE instance was created from a custom image, this id can then be used to identify it (see the “Equivalent REST response” accessible on each of the custom image descriptions in your Console’s [list](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/images?project=)).